# The following classes could not be found: android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change a `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout` in XML. Every time I do, I get the Missing Classes error:

```
The following classes could not be found: android.support.constraint.RelativeLayout
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RelativeLayout is not inside that package, you should use :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
```

Or if you are importing inside your class:

```
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
```

Comment: Genius! Didn't ever notice that.